# How to close a drop-down while opening another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript, I need help with my code.

I have two dropdowns that hold a a button and a container with links. How do I make one dropdown close while I open the other?

I have tried comparing the giving them different ids and comparing them but I am not sure I got that right.

```js
// achieve effect

// event delegation on body
let activeDropDown;
document.body.addEventListener('click', dropDown);

// event function for toggling class
function dropDown(ex) {
    // if (activeDropDown.id && activeDropDown.id !== ex.target.id) {
    //     activeDropDown.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('shower');
    // }

    if(ex.target.parentElement.classList.contains('am')) {
        let val;
        activeDropDown = ex.target.parentElement.id;
        activeDropDown.element = ex.target.parentElement;
        val = activeDropDown;
        ex.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('shower');
        console.log(val);
    }
}
// close the dropdown if the user click outside the button
window.addEventListener('click', closeDropDown);
// declaring the function 
function closeDropDown(ex2) {
    if (!ex2.target.matches('.arch-button')) {
        // getting the dropdowncontent
        let postDrop = document.querySelectorAll('.monthly-post');
        // var i;
        for (let i = 0; i < postDrop.length; i++) {
            let checkDropDown = postDrop[i];
            if (checkDropDown.classList.contains('shower')) {
                checkDropDown.classList.remove('shower');
            }           
        }   
    }
};
```

```css
 .am:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #C8C8C8;
 }
 .am:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 12px;
 }
 .monthly-post {
    position: relative;
    left: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;

 }
 .shower{
     overflow: visible !important;
     max-height: 100% !important;
     height: 100% !important;
     transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
     -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
     -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
     -ms-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
     -o-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}
 .post-linker {
     display: block;
     color: #0069E6;
 }
 .post-linker:hover,
 .post-linker:active{
     color: #21293C;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="am" id="am-march">
     <button class="arch-button">March 2019</button>
     <div class="monthly-post">
          <a href="" class="post-linker">TEF Application 2019</a>
          <a href="" class="post-linker">Big Brother 2019</a>
          <a href="" class="post-linker">Hotelo new Application for guest</a>
          <a href="" class="post-linker">Air peace easter promo</a>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="am"  id="am-april">
      <button class="arch-button">April 2019</button>
      <div class="monthly-post">
           <a href="" class="post-linker">ahahahah</a>
           <a href="" class="post-linker">ahahahah</a>
           <a href="" class="post-linker">ahahaha</a>
           <a href="" class="post-linker">ahahahahha</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I want the dropdrop to close while I open another dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.path` or `event.composedPath` to check the element is different, and close other drop-downs.

Answer (score 0):

Consume closeDropDown(); from dropDown() and remove click handlers.

```js
 let activeDropDown;
    document.body.addEventListener('click', dropDown);
    function dropDown(ex) {
        closeDropDown();
        if (ex.target.parentElement.classList.contains('am')) {
            let val;
            activeDropDown = ex.target.parentElement.id;
            activeDropDown.element = ex.target.parentElement;
            val = activeDropDown;
            ex.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('shower');
            console.log(val);
        }
    }   
    function closeDropDown() {
        let postDrop = document.querySelectorAll('.monthly-post');
        for (let i = 0; i < postDrop.length; i++) {
            let checkDropDown = postDrop[i];
            if (checkDropDown.classList.contains('shower')) {
                checkDropDown.classList.remove('shower');
            }
        }
    };
```

```css
 .am:not(:last-child) {
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid #C8C8C8;
    }

    .am:not(:first-child) {
        margin-top: 12px;
    }

    .monthly-post {
        position: relative;
        left: 17px;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 0;

    }

    .shower {
        overflow: visible !important;
        max-height: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
        -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
        -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
        -ms-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
        -o-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
    }

    .post-linker {
        display: block;
        color: #0069E6;
    }

    .post-linker:hover,
    .post-linker:active {
        color: #21293C;
    }
```

```html
<div class="am" id="am-march">
    <button class="arch-button">March 2019</button>
    <div class="monthly-post">
        <a href="" class="post-linker">TEF Application 2019</a>
        <a href="" class="post-linker">Big Brother 2019</a>
        <a href="" class="post-linker">Hotelo new Application for guest</a>
        <a href="" class="post-linker">Air peace easter promo</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="am" id="am-april">
    <button class="arch-button">April 2019</button>
    <div class="monthly-post">
        <a href="" class="post-linker">ahahahah</a>
        <a href="" class="post-linker">ahahahah</a>
        <a href="" class="post-linker">ahahaha</a>
        <a href="" class="post-linker">ahahahahha</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that made a lot of sense. i really appreciate .

Comment: i just noticed when i click again on the button it doesnt toggle the drop-down